# In Windows API programming how do I prevent mouse from leaving window?

Tags: winapi, mouse, hwnd

How do I limit mouse to one particular `HWND` in Win32 API programming? This `HWND` is not necessarily created by me. It could be a browser window, or photoshop program window. I'm trying to write a program that doesn't let mouse leave particular Windows program. I can get `HWND` of the program by `GetWindowText`.

Answer (score 4):

Check out MSDN: [ClipCursor function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648383%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

**ClipCursor function (winuser.h)**

Confines the cursor to a rectangular area on the screen. If a subsequent cursor position (set by the SetCursorPos function or the mouse) lies outside the rectangle, the system automatically adjusts the position to keep the cursor inside the rectangular area.

**Syntax**

```
BOOL ClipCursor(
  [in, optional] const RECT *lpRect
);
```

**Parameters**

[in, optional] lpRect

Type: const RECT*

A pointer to the structure that contains the screen coordinates of the upper-left and lower-right corners of the confining rectangle. If this parameter is NULL, the cursor is free to move anywhere on the screen.

**Return value**

Type: BOOL

If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.

If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.

**Remarks**

The cursor is a shared resource. If an application confines the cursor, it must release the cursor by using ClipCursor before relinquishing control to another application.

Comment: Thanks @Vlad. You're the man. Do you happen to know if this is per-application or global per-screen API? Looks like it's per screen? Meaning if I don't release the cursor then Windows is screwed because mouse can't move out of screen region?

Comment: It is global, but the documentation does not state whether it is per-monitor or not. I suspect that it is relative to the [virtual screen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145136.aspx) as a whole, not to any particular monitor. The documentation does state: "*Confines the cursor to a rectangular area on the screen. If a subsequent cursor position (set by the SetCursorPos function or the mouse) lies outside the rectangle, the system automatically adjusts the position to keep the cursor inside the rectangular area.*" I do not know whether the rect can span monitors...

Comment: The doc also states: "*The cursor is a shared resource. If an application confines the cursor, it must release the cursor by using ClipCursor before relinquishing control to another application.*" So yes, once the cursor is clipped to a rectangle, it cannot leave that rectangle until released.

Comment: This is only half an answer: While it does provide a way to confine mouse movement to a rectangular region, it won't tell you, how to connect this to a `HWND`. [GetWindowRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519.aspx) is only half a solution as well, as it doesn't account for changes in window size (or visibility).

Comment: @IInspectable - I made an assumption that the essence of that question was "how to constrain cursor position" and that bodacydo can take it from there, and apparently I was right :)

Comment: You misinterpret the goal of stackoverflow. It's not about helping a particular developer. Stackoverflow is about questions with answers, that are generally applicable. This answer does not address the question, and a missing *Accept* mark seems to indicate that.

Comment: @llnspectable then the answer should be, "read the documentation"

Comment: @Deleted Done. However, I was hoping that the reader can find documentation on the Win32 API given its name.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the edit. True, but just like a good restaurant, it's nice to know a little bit about a potential meal by reading what the menu says about it, before one orders.  +1 good sir.